# Android SImpleDateFormat not working for "yyyy-..."

Tags: android, date-format

When i try to rename a file using its last modified date, it is NOT working when using `dateformat ="yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm"` for example.

When i use:

```
dateformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH;mm;ss"
dateformat ="dd-MM-yyyy_HH;mm"
dateformat ="MM-dd-yyyy_HH;mm"
```

it works perfectly, but when trying to use year as first parameter it wouldn't rename the files.

```
        if (rb1.isChecked()) {
            dateformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH;mm;ss";
        } else if (rb2.isChecked()) {
            dateformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH;mm";
        } else if (rb3.isClickable()) {
            dateformat = "MM-dd-yyyy_HH;mm";
        } else if (rb3.isClickable()) {
            dateformat = "yyyy-dd-MM_HH;mm";
        } else if (rb4.isChecked()) {
            dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm";
        }
        else if (rb5.isChecked()) {
            dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM_HH;mm")
                    .format(new Date());
        } else if (rb6.isChecked()) {
            dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm;ss")
                    .format(new Date());
        }
```

I should NOT have used .isCickable, but .isChecked .....

Comment: the file[], what type of array?

Comment: Add your code in a nice `try catch (Exception e) { Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);}` you must have an exception somewhere, share it, and the solution must be quick!

Comment: I feel excesivly stupid with the pleasen support of Eclipse not learning (like vb) rom the user ...
rb3. and rb4. should NOT be .isClickable() but .isChecked() ...
Thank you all for your time here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this..

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm;ss").format(new Date());
```

**Update:** replace the following code snippet...

```
    if (rb1.isChecked()) {
        dateformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH;mm;ss";
    } else if (rb2.isChecked()) {
        dateformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH;mm";
    } else if (rb3.isClickable()) {
        dateformat = "MM-dd-yyyy_HH;mm";
    } else if (rb3.isClickable()) {
        dateformat = "yyyy-dd-MM_HH;mm";
    } else if (rb4.isChecked()) {
        dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm";
    }

    else if (rb5.isChecked()) {
        dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM_HH;mm")
                .format(new Date());
    } else if (rb6.isChecked()) {
        dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm;ss")
                .format(new Date());
    }
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateformat);
    String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lastModDate);
    newimgname = formattedDateString + ".jpg";
```

With...

```
if (rb1.isChecked()) {
    dateformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH;mm;ss";
} else if (rb2.isChecked()) {
    dateformat = "dd-MM-yyyy_HH;mm";
} else if (rb3.isClickable()) {
    dateformat = "MM-dd-yyyy_HH;mm";
} else if (rb3.isClickable()) {
    dateformat = "yyyy-dd-MM_HH;mm";
} else if (rb4.isChecked()) {
    dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm";
} else if (rb5.isChecked()) {
    dateformat = "yyyy-dd-MM_HH;mm";
} else if (rb6.isChecked()) {
    dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm;ss");
}

String formattedDateString = new SimpleDateFormat(dateformat).format(new Date());
newimgname = formattedDateString + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Nope, still the new file's name is 02-15-204_18;19.file

 lastModDate = new Date(file[i].lastModified());
 else if (rb6.isChecked()){dateformat =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH;mm;ss").format(new Date());}
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateformat);  
String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lastModDate); 
newimgname = ormattedDateString+".file";

Comment: Did it, when wrote the last comment here.